# How to add scroll IDs to WordPress menu anchors

Tags: menus, walker

In my theme the top menu is like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
       <li>
            <a class='active' data-scroll-nav='0'>Home</a>
       </li>
       <li>
            <a data-scroll-nav='1'>Services</a>
       </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

By using a custom walker function, I've been able to clean the `ul` and `li` tags of unwanted classes and IDs. Now I need to to add `"data-scroll-nav"`. How do I write a custom function to add this to the menu anchors? The menu code shown above will work like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/3/).

Answer (score 1):

Thank god.. i've solved it my own. this is the function i used to update the anchor tags.

```
function my_walker_nav($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

if(!empty( $item->description ))
    $description = $item->description;
else {
   $description = ''; 
}

 if ($item->menu_order == 1){

 $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a data-scroll-nav="'.$description.'" ', $item_output, 1);

}
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav', 10, 4);
```